# Is there a tutorial about giza++?

Tags: nlp, machine-translation, giza++

The Urls in its 'readme' file is not valid (http://www.fjoch.com/mkcls.html and http://www.fjoch.com/GIZA++.html). Is there a good tutorial about giza++? Or is there some alternatives that have complete documentation?

Comment: Second link is dead. Question is somewhat argumentative (what's a "good" tutorial?), too. You should try to improve it before it gets closed.

Comment: both links are dead...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955792/is-there-a-proper-installation-guide-for-giza-on-ubuntu/43274827#43274827

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/alvations/usaarhat-repo

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following is excerpted from a tutorial I'm putting together for a class. (NB: This assumes you have successfully installed GIZA++-v2 on a *nix system.)

---

1. Start with two data files containing parallel sentences that have been tokenized, one sentence per line. For example, a pair of parallel English-French files might read as follows.

Sample 1 - `train.en`

```
I gave him the book . 
He read the book . 
He loved the book .
```

Sample 2 - `train.fr`

```
Je lui ai donne/ le livre .
Il a lu le livre .
Il aimait le livre .
```

2. Run these files through `plain2snt.out` to get target and source vocabulary files (`*.vcb`) as well as a sentence pair file (`*.snt`).

From the GIZA++ directory, run:

```
./plain2snt.out TEXT1 TEXT2
```

where `TEXT1` and `TEXT2` are the data files described in step 1.

This produces four files in the same directory as `TEXT1` and `TEXT2` (assuming they are in the same directory):

- TEXT1_TEXT2.snt
- TEXT1.vcb
- TEXT2_TEXT1.snt
- TEXT2.vcb

The vocab files contain a unique (integer) ID for each word in the text (NB: not tokenized/lemmatized), the word/string, and the number of times that string occurred. These are separated by a single space character.

The sentence files contain numbers. For each sentence pair, there are three lines: the first is a count of the number of times that sentence pair occurs in the corpus and the second and third are a string of (space-separated) numbers corresponding to the entries for words in the vocab files. Based on the naming convention for `*.snt` files, the first file is assumed to be the source, and the second is assumed to be the target language. For example, in the file `TEXT1_TEXT2.snt`, the first line will be a count of the number of times the first sentence-pair occurred in the corpus, the second line will be a string of numbers corresponding to words in the `TEXT1.vcb` file, and the third line will be a string of numbers corresponding to words in the `TEXT2.vcb` file.

3. Now `TEXT1.vcb`, `TEXT2.vcb`, and either of the two `*.snt` files can be used as input to GIZA++ to produce an alignment.

For example:

```
./GIZA++ -s TEXT1.vcb -t TEXT2.vcb -c TEXT1_TEXT2.snt
```

But note that when I tried to run this, I had to rename `TEXT1_TEXT2.snt` to something without an underscore in the name in order to get any proper output.

Comment: thanks for your so long and complete answer!:)

Comment: If you got an error like: "ERROR: NO COOCURRENCE FILE GIVEN!",
you should produce a coocurrence file with "snt2cooc.out train.en.vcb train.fr.vcb corpus.snt > cooc.cooc" and then run "GIZA++ -S train.en.vcb -T train.fr.vcb -C corpus.snt -CoocurrenceFile cooc.cooc"

Comment: In some tutorials I found that they tell you to generate a *.vcb.classes file but I can't find any info on what it is or why you would need one. Could you perhaps elaborate on that?

Answer (score 3):

This Powerpoint tutorial worked for me: http://www.tc.umn.edu/~bthomson/wordalignment/GIZA.ppt

Comment: Not available any more.

Answer (score 3):

This one is very helpful :
http://fabioticconi.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/how-to-do-a-word-alignment-with-giza-or-mgiza-from-parallel-corpus/

IIT-B scholars have put up nice and detailed presentations for GIZA++ and MOSES setup and use.

Some of them are : 
http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~pb/cs712-2013/potpouri/kashyap-giza-mozes-jan2013.pdf

http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~anoopk/publications/presentations/moses_giza_intro.pdf

http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/Moses-Tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This one maybe ?

http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/issues/attachmentText?id=8&aid=697742396599277757&name=README-rst&token=40fba3d449abc12366b98b04cfe7dbc1

Full source : http://code.google.com/p/giza-pp/issues/detail?id=8

Answer (score 0):

There is a supplemental explanation of how to format input files and how to run GIZA++ over here:

http://www.tc.umn.edu/~bthomson/wordalignment/GIZAREADME.txt

Comment: Not available any more.