# Is there a proper installation guide for Giza++ on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, nlp, ubuntu-12.04, giza++

I see proper installation guide available for Giza, but not for Giza++. The instructions for installing the former (as found here http://giza.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html) is obviously not working on the latter. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: A similar Q&A could be helpful :)
Refer :: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23838428/2238884

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git-core pkg-config automake libtool wget zlib1g-dev python-dev libbz2-dev
git clone https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder.git 
cd mosesdecoder
make -f contrib/Makefiles/install-dependencies.gmake
./compile.sh
```

When you install Moses, GIZA++ is also installed in the `mosesdecoder/bin/` directory. See http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted

---

To install `MGIZA++`, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y cmake libboost-all-dev
git clone https://github.com/moses-smt/mgiza.git
cd mgiza/mgizapp
cmake . && make && make install
cp scripts/merge_alignment.py bin/
```

The binaries for MGIZA++ would be in `mgiza/mgizapp/bin/`.

Comment: Any particular reason why you copy `merge_alignment.py` to the bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the dependencies, simple install with:

```
$ wget https://giza-pp.googlecode.com/files/giza-pp-v1.0.7.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf giza-pp-v1.0.7.tar.gz 
$ cd giza-pp/
$ make
```

I've uploaded the pre-compiled binaries and you can get it here, but i'm not sure whether it works on your machine:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45771499/giza-binaries.zip
```

If you run into dependencies problems, simply install the dependencies required by the MOSES toolkit:

```
sudo apt-get install g++ git subversion automake libtool zlib1g-dev libboost-all-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev
```

Personally, I would just use the fast aligner which implemented IBM model 2 without the whole fuss about `mkcls`, see https://github.com/clab/fast_align

Comment: Three years on... See new answer.